# Is there such a thing as an intermediate value theorem in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have an exercise I want to solve, but got stuck in the second part due to not having something like the intermediate value theorem for the complex plane. The exercise is: Let $\Omega$ be an open set with $z_0 \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$. Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function with the property that

$f^{(k)}(z_0) \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for every } k = 0, 1, 2, ... $

First let $r > 0$ be such that the open interval $(z_0 - r, z_0 + r)$ is contained in $\Omega$. Prove that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in (z_0 - r, z_0 + r)$. Afterwards, let $\Omega$ be connected too and prove whether or not it follows that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$.

My solution is the following: since the derivatives in $z_0$ are real, we know that the coefficients of the power series expansion at $z_0$ are real. Therefore, for $x \in (z_0 - r, z_0 + r)$, we can use the power series expansion to evaluate $f(x)$. Since all the coefficients are real, we can conclude that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $x \in (z_0 -r, z_0 +r)$.

Now assume that $\Omega$ is connected too. Since $\Omega$ is connected and $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$ is non-empty, we can choose two real numbers $a$ and $b$, such that $a < b$ and $a, b \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$. Consider now the interval $(a,b)$. Because of the first part, we know that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. Since $f$ is continuous (holomorphic functions are continuous), it follows that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.
Now consider the interval $[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous on a closed interval, it attains its minimum and maximum values on that interval. By the intermediate value theorem (that doesn't exist in the complex plane?), there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)$ is the minimum or maximum value of $f$ on the interval. But since the first part, we know that $f(c)$ is real, such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in [a,b]$. Since $\Omega$ is connected, it follows that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$

Comment: you wrote "Since $\Omega$ is connected and $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$ is non-empty, we can choose two real numbers $a$ and $b$, such that $a < b$ and $a, b \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$. Consider now the interval $(a,b)$. Because of the first part, we know that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in (a,b)$."...  *This is not true*.  Consider e.g. $\Omega$ being the punctured open unit disc.  Then I select $a=-\frac{1}{2}=-b$.  You have asserted $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x \in (a,b)$ but $f(0)$ is undefined.  In terms of simple examples, e.g. $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Hint: look for a counter-example for the assigned exercise.

Comment: @user8675309 I now noticed that the theorem I use to conclude the first part, i.e. with the coefficients, relies on the disc centered at $z_0$ having a closure contained in $\Omega$, however this cannot be assumed to be true always, is that right?

Comment: you can't assume the intersectiion of two conected sets is connected -- that's really the flaw

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ be a regular curve and let $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Then, for any value $c$ between $f(\gamma(a))$ and $f(\gamma(b))$, there is a point $p\in \gamma([a,b])$ such that $f(p)=c$.

This is very straightforward to prove: Consider the function $f \circ\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ which is continuous, and apply the regular intermediate value theorem.

For me, this is a natural generalization of the intermediate value theorem for the complex plane. I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, this indeed seems like what I was looking for, but I am now unsure of how to apply it to my solution. I don’t have a function like the $f$ you describe and am not sure how to choose one